# Font awesome icon stack issue

Tags: html, fonts, stack, icons, font-awesome

So using this code

```
<li><a href="https://8ball.gg/"><i span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <span class="fa fa-stack-1x" style="color:black;">
          <span style="font-size:40px; margin-top:-20px;">
              8
          </span>
    </span>
    </i></a></li>
```

on jsfiddle.net works fine? But once i try and use it on my site i get a problem where its not stacked. screenshot - https://gyazo.com/3bbb79f81212e497a9a079ab7baf8836

If someone can help id appreciate

Comment: is it possible that another class in your site css is breaking it?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5c2b8825e822ac740370996ea353d36f Personally i dont see how they could be breaking it (I know the last part is messy but i was testing)

Comment: Please can someone help?